# How to activate an option of a menubar from an external button on PrimeFaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a query, I happen to have a dynamic menubar, internally you sending parameters that load on the associated screen, the query I have is how to activate the menuitem from an external button, I mean on the screen position, associate a button that invokes the option of menuItem.

[image]

**MenuItem code generated in the menubar:**

```
<li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('menuForm',{'vdesOpcForm':'menuItemCotizaciones','j_idt46:j_idt55':'j_idt46:j_idt55','menuItemCotizaciones005':'menuItemCotizaciones005','menuItemCotizaciones006':'menuItemCotizaciones006','j_idt46:j_idt55_menuid':'2_9','menuItemCotizaciones003':'menuItemCotizaciones003','menuItemCotizaciones004':'menuItemCotizaciones004','menuItemCotizaciones001':'menuItemCotizaciones001','menuItemCotizaciones002':'menuItemCotizaciones002'}).submit('menuForm');return false;" href="#" tabindex="-1">
<span class="ui-menuitem-text">Cotizaciones</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Id assigned MenuItem so dynamic in the menubar: **menuItemCotizaciones**

CommandButton where I try to invoke the action of menuItem generated so dynamic

```
<p:commandButton value="SALIR++" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('menuForm',{'vdesOpcForm':'menuItemCotizaciones','j_idt46:j_idt55':'j_idt46:j_idt55','menuItemCotizaciones005':'menuItemCotizaciones005','menuItemCotizaciones006':'menuItemCotizaciones006','j_idt46:j_idt55_menuid':'2_9','menuItemCotizaciones003':'menuItemCotizaciones003','menuItemCotizaciones004':'menuItemCotizaciones004','menuItemCotizaciones001':'menuItemCotizaciones001','menuItemCotizaciones002':'menuItemCotizaciones002'}).submit('menuForm');" />
```

if I tried it and it worked, but the issue is that would have to give all that data into hard in the onclick attribute, there is no way for jQuery to invoke the onclick of menuItem generated with their current parameters that have ...

**Something like this code in Jquery.**

```
<p:button value="SALIR++33" id="btnSalir" onclick="$('#btnSalir').click($('#menuItemCotizaciones').attr('onclick'));" />
```

Comment: The last approach you tried should work. You just have to find the  right reference to the menu item you want to click on

Comment: If I'm trying to watch it possible to invoke the dynamic menuItem from an external button PrimeFaces ...

Comment: ??? Sorry, I do not understand this